# Why isn't my css container working?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to put a container around my images to control the height of an image.

For some reason my container css height isn't working. It's been a while since i've needed to use css so i'm a little rusty.

I'm creating an ionic application with angularjs. That's why the code may look slightly odd to some of you but that excess code shouldn't have an impact on the css.

I have may a codepen to get help someone answer my question: http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/eNMgzG

Here's my code
HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Gallery" align-title="center">

<ion-content class="center" ng-controller="photoCtrl" ng-init="getImages()">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 3 === 0">
        <div id="container" class="col col-25" ng-if="$index < images.length">
            <img class="image" ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length">
            <img class="image" ng-src="{{images[$index + 1].src}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length">
            <img class="image" ng-src="{{images[$index + 2].src}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length">
            <img class="image" ng-src="{{images[$index + 2].src}}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

 #container { 
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
 }

 .image {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
 }
```

Comment: What's the actual result you're after?

Comment: to get the image's height the same as with widths.

Comment: @smither123 So...you want to stretch them? I find it unlikely that's considered best for presentation. You might be able to pull off some auto-center-cropping at zero zoom if you change them into background-images.

Comment: If i added center cropping would i then be able to get them the correct size by using a container? I'm not sure if i could use them as background images as they can't be static. They'd have to move with the scroll. That possible?

Comment: Cropping them is not an ideal solution either. When working with images you want them to be the same size to start with, because re-sizing and stuff almost never works out well when you got a grid system with lots of squares.

Comment: The idea was that the user could press on the image and it will load the full size image. The grid images are just meant to be icons previewing the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `height: 100%` unless the parent element also has it. So I wouldn't recommend actually using it. It's far easier setting the height to 100% using javascript, which won't require the parent to also have the `height: 100%`.

Update: You can't use any % value like this. A better solution is to let the content expand the container instead of setting a fixed value on the container.

Comment: I would like the hight in the container to 25%. I was just using 100% as an example to show it wasn't doing anything. Should i still set it to 25% using javascript?

Comment: @smither123 You can't use % at all this way. So yes you should or just let the content expand the container instead.

Comment: How would i let the content expand the container instead?

Comment: @smither123 Is there a reason you need to set a height on the container?

Comment: Yes, i would like all the images to be the same size. In my HTML i've currently got a grid set up so each image takes up 25% width of the page. I would like the height on each image so it's more visual appealing

Comment: @smither123 it will never look good if the images are of different size to begin with, you you want to crop the images before hand to a certain size.

Comment: Can i turn them into thumbnails then?

Comment: @smither123 Yes you can.

Comment: @smither123 Consider accepting this answer if you've gotten your question answered.

Comment: Okay. I will do. So there is no possible way to use css % to change the height?

Comment: @smither123 Like I said, you would have to traverse the height all the way up to the html tag. But that is NOT a good solution, if adding elements you're gonna have to keep setting the height to 100% of those you added as well.

Comment: I'm guessing the best solution is to ever use media queries or javascript to resize when the browser resizes?

Comment: @smither123 Media queries.